# Enable Remote console for vmware 5.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, remote, vmware-vcenter, console

There is a nice feature - at least in my opinion - in VMware 6.5 that I have seen yesterday: Remote console.

How can I add this feature to vmware 5.5?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [download](http://www.vmware.com/go/download-vmrc) it from VMware and install it on your management workstation in accordance with the instructions.

It requires a minimum vSphere version of 5.5 Update 2b, which is build 2183109, 2183111 or 2183112 depending on how you've installed it. See https://www.vmware.com/support/vsphere5/doc/vsphere-vcenter-server-55u2b-release-notes.html for more details.

BTW, https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1014508 will point you at the right page for all version numbers for all VMware products, should you want to check yourself.

Comment: I see, still in the context menu the option to run remote console for this virtual machine doesn't exist..

Comment: What version of the vSphere are you running? I believe it requires 5.5 U2b or newer.

Comment: vcenter 5.5.0 Build 2001466, vsphere 5.5 Build 2068190, I am not sure what the update numbers are, but sounds like update 2

Comment: It looks like you have update 2, but not 2b; that's build 2183109, 2183111 or 2183112 depending on how you've installed it. See https://www.vmware.com/support/vsphere5/doc/vsphere-vcenter-server-55u2b-release-notes.html for more details. (BTW, https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1014508 will point you at the right page for all version numbers for all VMware products, should you want to check yourself.)

Comment: Please make this an answer

Comment: @elegeek - done!